# Ссылка на шаблон внутри CSS/JS в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте. В WordPress для того, чтобы получить ссылку на директорию текущей темы используется функция [bloginfo()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/bloginfo) с параметром *template_url*.

Но что делать с файлами и ссылками, которые используются внутри CSS и JS-файлов? К примеру:

```
.sect1 .sect-bg {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(images/bg-screen1.jpg) no-repeat 50% 40% fixed;
}
```

или

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {'email' : email, 'act' : act},

        success: function(response){
        $('#subscription_success').html(response.message);
   }
```

Если ссылки оставить таковыми - они не подключаются, лишь если указать полный URL, что не особо правильно.

Comment: Вероятно, не совсем понял вопрос вначале. Расширил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте путь относительно папки темы. Чтобы его получить, надо вызвать get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). Это при формировании страницы или скриптов в php.

Если же надо "вручную" описывать относительные пути в css, то показанная вами конструкция работает. Дело, скорее всего, в неправильном размещении папок. Еcли, допустим, ваш css файл в вопросе расположен в

```
/wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css
```

то изображение должно находиться здесь:

```
/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/bg-screen1.jpg
```

Для ajax нужен полный путь. Но в WordPress так, как вы написали, обычно не делают. В functions.php темы в хуке wp_enqueue_sripts:

```
wp_register_script('my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-script.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('my-script');
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'my_script_ajax',
    array(
        'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('my-nonce')
    )
);
```

В my-script.js:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: my_script_ajax.url,
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
      if (response.success) {
          $(container).html(response.data);
          return true;
      } else {
          $(container).html(response.data);
          return false;
      }
  },
  async: false
});
```

Подробнее про ajax в WordPress можно почитать на [указанном вами сайте](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

Answer (score 1):

> используется функция bloginfo() с параметром template_url.

Стоит использовать [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) если нужно без учёта дочерней темы или [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) если с учётом дочки.